# ActionBarSherlock does not export R to the library

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've built the ABS with Eclipse to the JAR-library, and trying to use it with IntelliJ IDEA. All the source code is exported well, but not resources - there is no R.java in the library.
Min SDK is 10, target - 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can not access resource from a jar file, you have to add the resources separately to your project.